# Getting empty dataframe after foreachPartition execution in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm kinda new in PySpark and I'm trying to perform a foreachPartition function in my dataframe and then I want to perform another function with the same dataframe.
The problem is that after using the foreachPartition function, my dataframe gets empty, so I cannot do anything else with it. My code looks like the following:

```
def my_random_function(partition, parameters):
    #performs something with the dataframe
    #does not return anything

my_py_spark_dataframe.foreachPartition(
    lambda partition: my_random_function(partition, parameters))
```

Could someone tell me how can I perform this foreachPartition and also use the same dataframe to perform other functions?

I saw some users talking about copying the dataframe using df.toPandas().copy() but in my case this causes some perform issues, so I would like to use the same dataframe instead of creating a new one.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which operation you are trying; but here is a sample usage of [foreachPartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreachPartition.html):

The sample data is a list of coutries from three continents:

```
+---------+-------+
|Continent|Country|
+---------+-------+
|       NA|    USA|
|       NA| Canada|
|       NA| Mexico|
|       EU|England|
|       EU| France|
|       EU|Germany|
|     ASIA|  India|
|     ASIA|  China|
|     ASIA|  Japan|
+---------+-------+
```

Following code partitions the data by "Continent", iterates each partition using `foreachPartition` and writes the "Country" name to each file of that specific partition i.e. continent.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["NA", "USA"], ["NA", "Canada"], ["NA", "Mexico"], ["EU", "England"], ["EU", "France"], ["EU", "Germany"], ["ASIA", "India"], ["ASIA", "China"], ["ASIA", "Japan"]], schema=["Continent", "Country"])
df.withColumn("partition_id", F.spark_partition_id()).show()

df = df.repartition(F.col("Continent"))
df.withColumn("partition_id", F.spark_partition_id()).show()

def write_to_file(rows):
  for row in rows:
    with open(f"/content/sample_data/{row.Continent}.txt", "a+") as f:
      f.write(f"{row.Country}\n")

df.foreachPartition(write_to_file)
```

Output:

Three files: one for each partition.

```
!ls -1 /content/sample_data/

ASIA.txt
EU.txt
NA.txt
```

Each file has country names for that continent (partition):

```
!cat /content/sample_data/ASIA.txt
India
China
Japan

!cat /content/sample_data/EU.txt
England
France
Germany

!cat /content/sample_data/NA.txt
USA
Canada
Mexico
```

Comment: Hello @Azhar Khan thank you for you reply!
I do understand how to use the foreachPartition, but the problem I'm facing is that after using it, my dataframe gets empty. In your example, after using the "df.foreachPartition(write_to_file)" the df variable gets empty with no row on it.
Using your example, what I would like to do is write the countries to files, but also still have the df filled to use in another operation, for example, sending it to an API or writing to a database

Comment: No, it does not empty the dataframe. You can run above code and print dataframe at the end using `df.show()`, you will still see all records. Are you assigning output of `df.foreachPartition()` to df something like `df = df.foreachPartition(...)`? [foreachPartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreachPartition.html) does not return anything.

Comment: Hum... Actually no, I'm not.

Comment: So the empty data frame doesn't have anything related with the foreachPartition, right?

Comment: You can try it to be more sure. In my example above, just assign `df = df.foreachPartition(...)` and print it.